# How to avoid null/undefined check on JS/Typescript singleton with init function

Tags: javascript, typescript, design-patterns, singleton, coding-style

I'm trying to find a pattern to avoid having to null/undefined check each literal props defined in an Object literal that is dynamically initiated only once at some point.
This object would serve as a singleton in a lifecycle of the application.

Is there a way to make this cleaner and avoid having to check and throw for each method that depends on the init to have happened? And also avoid `!` operator on each prop once I know it is properly initiated?

I also want `method2` to be able to be called before the `init` so that I can enqueue some things...
I guess I could switch my Object for a class and constructor (and define an instance as per singleton pattern) but the props for the constructor are needed from outside the class.
My `method2` would also not be available until first constructed, unless I move it out of that class.

Any help appreciated.

```
interface StuffType {
  x?: string;
  y?: string;
  z?: string;
  fn?: () => void;
  isInit: boolean;
}

const _stuff: StuffType = {
  x: undefined,
  y: undefined,
  z: undefined,
  fn: undefined,
  isInit: false,
};

const isReady = () => _stuff.isInit;

const init = (x: string, y: string, z: string, fn: () => void) => {
  if(_stuff.isInit) return;
  _stuff.x = x;
  _stuff.y = y;
  _stuff.z = z;
  _stuff.fn = fn;
};

const method1 = () => {
  // depends on xyz, fn being defined
  if (!_stuff.isInit) throw new Error('not init');
  _stuff.fn!();
  _stuff.x!;
  _stuff.y!;
  _stuff.z!;
};

// All the following methods would depend on init being done
// would require check on init/throw error/bang operator on props
// const method3 = () =>
// const method4 = () =>
// const method5 = () =>
// const method6 = () =>

const method2 = () => {
  // does not depend on xyz, fn
};

export const Stuff = {
  init,
  isReady,
  method1,
  method2,
  //etc...
};

Stuff.method2(); // fine
Stuff.method1(); // throws here
Stuff.init('x', 'y', 'z', () => console.log('init'));
Stuff.method1(); // does not throw
```

Comment: Why is `method2` even part of the object if it doesn't use it? Sounds very much as if it *should* be independent.

Comment: I guess it could be outside but is dependent on the init of the object, to make it more clear, the Object is basically a subscribe/publish type object. Until it's initialized (has dependencies on other parts of the application for those publish/sub  that are async), I want to enqueue request to that subscribe, on init clear the queue. But yea, could definitely outside of the object but in the same module, but I will need to expose isReady to that method or access the object prop directly.

Answer (score 1):

To do this more concisely, I'd put the data to be initialized in a single separate property - that way, you just need to check if that one property exists. This also makes the `isInit` property superfluous.

```
interface StuffType {
  data?: {
    x: string;
    y: string;
    z: string;
  }
  fn?: () => void;
}
const _stuff: StuffType = {
  fn: undefined,
};
const init = (x: string, y: string, z: string, fn: () => void) => {
  _stuff.data ??= { x, y, z };
};
const method1 = () => {
  const { data } = _stuff;
  if (!data) throw new Error('not init');
  _stuff.fn!();
  data.x;
  data.y;
  data.z;
};
```

> I also want method2 to be able to be called before the init so that I can enqueue some things

Nothing in `method2`'s signature shows that it depends on anything else, so no real modification there is necessary; you're free to populate

```
const method2 = () => {
  // does not depend on xyz, fn
};
```

with whatever you want. (Perhaps you could have a queue variable local to the module, `const queue = []`, that gets pushed to if `method2` is called)

Comment: That's way better, don't know why I didn't think about that. For each new method I would still need to check that precondition though...

Comment: Personally, I don't like mutating objects, and TypeScript often doesn't *just work* as great compared to when you don't mutate. Depending on the type of a mutable outer scope variable means that such a check will have to be performed every time. I'd prefer to either require initialization immediately, or to only return the object with data and methods when initialized (and not before then).

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid a partial type where every property is optional by itself. You can make them dependent on each other by using a discriminated union:

```
interface Stuff {
  isInit: true;
  x: string;
  y: string;
  z: string;
  fn: () => void;
}

type MaybeStuff = Stuff | { isInit: false };

const _stuff: MaybeStuff = {
  isInit: false,
};

export const method1 = () => {
  if (!_stuff.isInit) throw new Error('not initialised');
  // depends on x, y, z, fn being initialised
  _stuff.fn();
  _stuff.x;
  _stuff.y;
  _stuff.z;
};
```

However, an even simpler solution is to make `_stuff` a mutable variable that is initially `undefined`:

```
interface Stuff {
  x: string;
  y: string;
  z: string;
  fn: () => void;
}

let _stuff: Stuff | undefined; /*
^^^ */

export const isReady = () => _stuff !== undefined;

export function init(x: string, y: string, z: string, fn: () => void) {
  if (_stuff) return; // throw new Error('already initialised');
  stuff = {x, y, z, fn};
};

export function method1() {
  if (!_stuff) throw new Error('not initialised');
  // depends on _stuff being initialised
  _stuff.fn();
  _stuff.x;
  _stuff.y;
  _stuff.z;
}

export function method2() {
  // does not depend on xyz, fn
}
```

If you do not like repeating the `if (!_stuff) …` line in all the methods that need the stuff, make a helper function for them:

```
function get(): Stuff {
  if (!_stuff) throw new Error('not initialised');
  return _stuff;
}
export function method1() {
  const stuff = get(); // depends on _stuff being initialised
  stuff.fn();
  stuff.x;
  stuff.y;
  stuff.z;
}

export function method2() {
  // does not depend on xyz, fn
}

export function method3() {
  const stuff = get(); // depends on _stuff being initialised
  …
}
```

> [I have] an Object literal that is dynamically initiated only once at some point. This object would serve as a singleton in a lifecycle of the application. Is there a way to make this cleaner?

Yes, that doesn't sound a lot like a singleton, or at least like one with all of the common known singleton problems. A proper singleton should already be initialised at the start of the application, not at some point in its lifecycle, and it should not need parameters passed to it (exactly once). If it is parameterised, sooner or later you will need (multiple) different instances with different configuration.

So rather, refactor your module into a `class`, remove the mutable `_stuff` static (module-scoped) variable and the `init` method. Construct your object where the parameter values are available, and have *that* module be responsible for providing the instance to the rest of the application (via a global variable, the singleton pattern, dependency injection, etc.).

Also the `method2` should either be a `static` method of the class if it is stateless, or it should be a method of the module keeping the initialisation state (if it does what you describe, enqueuing things until the initialisation).